# Use model of diiferent name in a different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-3, activemodel

I have a controller FormsController and a Active Model ApplicationForm. I have made this model by including `include ActiveModel::Validations`, `include ActiveModel::Conversion`, `extend ActiveModel::Naming`. When I'm using `@form=ApplicationForm` I'm getting `NameError uninitialized constant FormsController::ApplicationForm`. How do I resolve this issue, I just want to use this Model as class which can provide object to hold form values temporarily for further processing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to use it from a directory.  Assuming it is in a directory app/forms and you have done correctly added the forms to the autoload paths for rails.

```
@form = ::Forms::ApplicationForm.new(your_params)
```

Your module will have to be named like this

```
module Forms
  class ApplicationForm
    #your form code
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! But if I keep my model file in some other directory, how do I use it?

Comment: you will have to change a couple things.  I'll update answer to get you what you need.